# Phone company keeping password in clear text

Tags: passwords

I recently found out that the Phone company where I have my contract is storing passwords on their server in clear text and employees can access it given the name or contract number of a person.

There is no discussion about that being insecure...

How can I raise my concern on that matter to the company effectively?

Comment: http://plaintextoffenders.com/ - You can't really raise your concern there but it's a good site.

Comment: This sounds more legal question than security question.

Comment: Get a lawyer and file a lawsuit for malpractice of data handling. P.S I'm not an attorney and I don't know what that would legally fall under, however, data laws are mostly everywhere. Please don't take this as legal advice though.

Comment: @Joshua.J how about asking the company first?

Comment: @schroeder That could also work, however, I find in these scenarios one person coming forward and having an issue usually does nothing and they either ignore you or make something up.